# add and remove element on jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to make an UI where you can add a group of element inside of container without duplicating and it can delete itself. here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var element = document.getElementById();

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").click(function(e){
        var node = (e.target).cloneNode(true);
        $('.smallInnerBox').append(node);
    });

    $("button").click(function(e){
        $(".m").detach();
    });

});

</script>

<h1>jQuery clone() example</h1>

<a href="#"><div class="m">div 1<button>remove</button></div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="m">div 2</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="m">div 3</div></a>

<div class="smallBox">
    I'm a small box
</div>

<div class="smallInnerBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click event handle needs to prevent the page from reloading when the anchor is clicked.

```
$("a").click(function(e)
{
    var node = (e.target).cloneNode(true);
    $('.smallInnerBox').append(node);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I should add that your code still won't do what I think you are expecting it to do, but hopefully that'll get you a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

This works with jQuery 1.9.1 - see: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AP4Ar/9/)

```
//var element = document.getElementById(); // remove this line

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").click(function(e){
        $(e.target).clone(true, true).appendTo('.smallInnerBox');
    });

    $("button").on('click', function(e){
        $(".m").detach();
    });

});
```

But it removes too much elements ;)

Comment: thanks for giving me an idea

Comment: I never known `clone` function before so I learned something too (digging in Google and jQuery docs), thx :)